# Как работать с RestApi Client в Visual Studio сгенерированным из JSON?

Tags: c#, json, http, rest

Мне передали JSON файл который генерирует классы, которые я должен использовать для клиента RESTAPI. Существует легенда, что используя эти классы я могу создать клиент, без написания рутинных операций (якобы он сам все делает, нужно только вызвать соответствующий метод). Вот только как с ними работать? Как вызывать эти методы? Документации по этому вопросу нигде найти не могу. Единственная статья на эту тему, которую мне удалось найти , но это не совсем то что мне нужно.
Буду рад любым советам и ссылкам. 
Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся.=)

Answer (score 0):

Сам Json файл ничего не генерирует. Это просто текстовый формат обмена данными.
Если вы хотите транслировать json в c# классы то можете воспользоваться встроенными инструментами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или сервисами вроде [этого](http://json2csharp.com/).
Что до вашей "легенды"...Запросы всё равно придётся писать. Либо используя HttpClient, либо опенсорсный RestSharp, например.

Comment: Совершенно верно, вот только принимаю я этот файл через autorest, и классы формируются, только формирует оно его в извращенном виде, все попытки работать с этими классами, не к чему не приводят, тут собственно я и застопорился, так как документация по autorest скудная, а задачу решить нужно, может есть какие то tutorial по autorest? Руками все это делать - не вариант, так как классов больше 500.

Comment: Интернет [подсказывает](https://medium.com/@pjausovec/creating-c-client-library-for-web-api-projects-be132c831f9c), что следует использовать autorest в связке со swagger'ом. От себя добавить ничего не смогу, ибо autorest'ом не пользовался.